# What is the advantage of using a HDMI connection over DVI

Tags: av-cable

Other than the form factor (DVI cable looks clunkier) and the fact that HDMI also carries audio.

Is the video signal better?

Comment: Are they both digital? Then no, there's no "better" quality, in normal usage parameters.

Comment: Yes, I think they are both digital

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For most applications, DVI and HDMI are both the same picture quality wise. The only difference is the connection type and the fact that HDMI can carry both video and audio.

http://hdmivsdvi.com/

> DVI and HDMI are exactly the same as one another, image-quality-wise.

http://www.ecoustics.com/electronics/products/articles/122868.html

> you should not expect any difference when moving from DVI to HDMI,

http://EzineArticles.com/394968

> Because HDMI evolved from DVI, they are both identical when it comes to video.

http://www.abccables.com/info-dvi-hdmi.html

See also [HDMI vs Component vs VGA vs DVI vs DisplayPort](https://superuser.com/q/15884/52492)

Answer (score 1):

> Q. What is the difference between DVI and HDMI?
>
> HDMI is DVI with the addition of:
>
> - Audio (up to 8-channels uncompressed)
> - Smaller connector
> - Support for YUV color space
> - CEC (Consumer Electronics Control)
> - CEA-861B infoframes

http://www.hdmi.org/learningcenter/faq.aspx#83