# Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT with DVI + HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi

SO I've got this old Nvidia 9500 GT in which I'm right now connecting a VGA and a DVI monitor. I've now bought a new HDMI screen, and I would like to ditch my old VGA screen, and use this one instead.

What I would like to know, is if it will work normally, or if I'll need to get a new video card. It's been working with VGA + DVI, but I've been told it might mot work with DVI + HDMI. Is that so?

Comment: What outputs does the card have? Does your DVI monitor have any VGA inputs you can use? See our [Community FAQ on connector types](http://superuser.com/questions/15884/hdmi-vs-component-vs-vga-vs-dvi-vs-displayport/252864#252864); that might help clear things up for you.

Comment: My card has all the three

Comment: then why not just use the HDMI output? I'm not sure I get what your question is.

Comment: Am I correct in saying you are hooking up two monitors? Thus the VGA + DVI?