# How to make Windows 7 remember that I want extended display?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi

After consulting [HDMI vs Component vs VGA vs DVI vs DisplayPort](https://superuser.com/questions/15884/hdmi-vs-component-vs-vga-vs-dvi-vs-displayport), I've decided to buy a HDMI cable to connect laptop with external display. Before that I've used a VGA cable.

I've set up dual-head display and checked *Multiple displays: Extend these displays* in *Control Panel* -> *All Control Panel Items* -> *Display* -> *Screen Resolution*.

The **problem** is that every time my laptop decides to turn off displays, after I woke up it, the settings return to default *Multiple displays: Show desktop only on 1* and I have to manually switch it to *Extend these displays*. Which is, as you can imagine, very annoying. The problem didn't occur when I used the VGA cable.

- Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I think this has something to do with HDMI display sending *receiver disconnected* to the laptop. It just looks like Windows thinks that a new monitor has been connected every time.

My **configuration**: Windows 7 x64 running on ASUS N76V Laptop with Intel HD Graphics 4000 and NVIDIA GeForce 650M. External display: NEC MultiSync EA244WMi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been **solved** after **laptop reboot**.

I wouldn't reboot the PC my self, but after waking it up and turning on the monitor (on a login screen of Windows 7), a BSoD happened. Now every time I wake up computer after Windows turns off displays, *Extend theses displays* works out of the box.