# connecting DVI monitor to HDMI port

Tags: display, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, cable

Can I connect computer monitor with the case by using DVI to HDMI cable?
monitor side is DVI and the case side id HDMI.
I want to choose the correct cable for this connection.

My graphic card is 2 GB build in

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need an adapter HDMI to DVI.

There are two kinds: HDMI male to DVI female, with this you will need a DVI cable.
[image: HDMI > DVI adapter]

And a HDMI female to DVI male, in this one you will need a HDMI cable.

For more information you should read [this great answer](https://superuser.com/questions/15884/hdmi-vs-component-vs-vga-vs-dvi-vs-displayport/252864#252864) about different ports, qualities and ways for connect them.

Comment: I bought the HDMI - DVI cable, and I connected the computer monitor to the computer case, BUT nothing appear, which means it is useless.
is there any configuration on the computer that make the HDMI port as an output display port ? how I can do that?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
and the graphic card in onboard NVIDIA GeForce 7300 LE 2 GB

Comment: You have to configure the output. Hold at the same time the key Windows+P http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976064

Comment: still have problem

Comment: How to configure HDMI onboard port to be the output port?

Comment: Ok. Shutdown the computer, disconnect the dvi port, connect only the hdmi port, boot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16623/discussion-between-barznjy-and-n00b).